# Why will my After Effects script run from the menu but not from Command Line?

Tags: windows, command-line, after-effects

I'm trying to run a .jsx file I've written from commandline, but it will not work. When I call "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects 2020\Support Files\AfterFX.exe" -r script.jsx" After Effects opens and quickly closes, without even modifying the project or appearing to do anything. When I click on File > Script > Run Script inside of AE, it works perfectly fine and the project saves. I also added some alerts to my script which trigger when called from the File menu but not from commandline, making it clear that nothing is happening. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was using relative path for script path. Windows only accepts absolute path as valid for aescripts when running from command line.

Command to run on Windows (NOTE: Always use full paths!)

PowerShell:
`& "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects 2022\Support Files\AfterFX.exe" -noui -r "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\alert.js"`

Command Prompt
`"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects 2022\Support Files\AfterFX.exe" -noui -r "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\alert.js"`

NOTE: both scripts are using flags `-noui` (no ui) and `-r` (run script)